# Moving the contents of a div to the bottom of code

Tags: css, html, web, document-ready

On the website I am currently working on I have a div that loads slowly causing the page to load slowly but also jump as not all the positions elements load until after this slow div does. I cannot control the contents of this div as the content from the div comes from an external source.
So I was wondering if I could move the contents of this div to the bottom of my code so that it loads after the rest of my page whilst still keeping the position of the content on the same place on the webpage? Similar to what people do with some java script code.

Comment: show us some code on what have you tried

Comment: As you yourself imply, this can indeed be done with Javascript. More info is required to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Sergey said do something like this

javascript in the head
    window.onLoad = function() { switchDivs(); }

HTML above where you want the content

```
<div id="whereYouWantIt"></div>
```

More HTML for the rest of your page

```
<div id="contentIsInHere"></div>
```

javascript here for function that switches the content around. Optionally call an external script here that contains this function.

```
<script> 
function switchDivs() {
  document.getElementById("whereYouWantIt").innerHTML = document.getElementById("contentIsInHere").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("contentIsInHere").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("whereYouWantIt").style.display = "inline";
}
</script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
#whereYouWantIt {
    display:none;
    other styles ...
}
#contentIsInHere {
    display:none;
    no other styles needed
}
```

Comment: I would if I had the rep to.

Comment: @user1738676 I just upped you. You should be able to now click the check next to my answer then after it gives you rep for that your should be able to up click too. Did you go with the javascript or the absolute positioning?

Comment: I tried the JS but I just ended up with a loading bar with nothing happening after the page had loaded. Also had to add () after function on the first line. But the CSS way got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to position the div and have it in the end. Or javascript is actually is good idea, load the content in a window.onload() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate 2 divs - one where it should be and second in the bottom of page. Both of elements should have initially display none. After page will be loaded copy inner content of "pseudo" div  by using JavaScript  to the div you needed and make display block for this.